# Re-projecting shapefile from an unknown projection

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, shapefile, coordinate-system

I have been given a shapefile which is supposedly in a NAD1927_Zone16 projection. I need to align it with a raster image in a Lambert Conformal Conic (NAD 1927) projection.

I've tried to use the Project and Define Projection tools to verify that this shapefile is in NAD1927_Zone16, but when I compare to other data it is no where near where it should be (leading me to believe that the projection indicated on the shapefile is not correct).

In addition, I've edited the Standard Paralell and Latitude of Origin and Central Meridian values as per: 
https://geonet.esri.com/thread/9764

And I've also tried loading in a custom projection from a .prj file downloaded from the following site:
http://spatialreference.org/ref/esri/102002/

I haven't done much with projections or transformations before, but I really didn't expect it to be this complicated when I agreed to the task.

Comment: Re-projecting is trivial once you've identified the source coordinate system, but impossible without it.  Please review the options in the previously answered question.

Comment: I'll check out those options! Thanks, I didn't see this link when I was looking around earlier.

Comment: Maybe do this on geonet, if you have an account--post the question but include the data's extent, and what area it represents (city, park, county, etc.). Someone there may be able to help. Feel free to @Melita Kennedy so I see it quickly.